# custom viewcontroller from storyboard cannot be found in project structure

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I created a new `ViewController` on `main.storyboard`, `labels`, `buttons` added manually, but I did not see this `viewController` in the project structure to customize it programatically and move it to the view folder.

Is it a bug, or I missed something? Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a `UIViewController` class and assign it to the `ViewController` you created in `storyBoard`.

Comment: Create UIViewController class file and assign it to ViewController which u dragged from Object Library... Please don't forget to upvote the answers who did effort for you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm newbie, my bad. @MRizwan33, sure will do that. RajeshKumar was the first and he gave the only answer.I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new file for every viewcontroller you add to the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the gif, really appreciate that! Just fyi, I had to restart my xcode because the viewcontroller selector was empty.